# Lambda Variable Assignment (for Tkinter command callbacks)

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, ttk

I was trying to learn a bit more about Tkinter and came across this code online

```
import Tkiner
import ttk
root = Tk()
l =ttk.Label(root, text="Starting...")
l.grid()
l.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: l.configure(text='Moved mouse inside'))
l.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: l.configure(text='Moved mouse outside'))
l.bind('<1>', lambda e: l.configure(text='Clicked left mouse button'))
l.bind('<Double-1>', lambda e: l.configure(text='Double clicked'))
l.bind('<B3-Motion>', lambda e: l.configure(text='right button drag to %d,%d' % (e.x, e.y)))
root.mainloop()
```

When I ran this program, and dragged my mouse over the screen while the RMB was pressed it gave me the coordinates as is mentioned it should do in the "B3-Motion" bind.

What exactly does the temp variable "e" refer to in this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just the first argument to the function − in this case the event that Tkinter sends when you click a button.

Comment: [Under the event attributes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind a function to an event with `widget.bind(...)`, tkinter will always pass in an argument to the function that represents the event when it calls the function. Typically this is named `event`, but sometimes abbreviated as `e`.

The event object has information about the event, such as which widget received the event, the x/y coordinate of the cursor when the event occurred, and other useful information.

You can read a bit more about that object here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm
.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :D